# Python List Does Not Give Me Value Associated With Number Entered In Brackets

Tags: python, list

I am trying to make a program that will take product Id's and put them at the end of a URL. This URL is then later crawled and the information needed (Specifications) is put in a text file. I am running into a problem reading the PID's and putting them into a list. When I run my code, it does fine, it reads the PID's from a .txt file and converts each PID to a part of a list. I know this works because I then use it correctly in a for statement. I think my probelm is that it is storing it as a list in a list, how can I stop this from happening or how can I access a PID by using something like PID[3]. Right now only PID[0] works and it gives me the whole list... Here is what my code looks like:

```
URLList = []
PID = [open("PID.txt").read().split()]

#Turn the PID's into links to where their product can be found: Store as a list of URL's
for whole in PID:
    for code in whole:
        URLList.append("http://www.abb.com/productdetails/" + code)
```

As you can see, I have to use 2 for loops to access the PID's. If someone could let me know of an error I'm making, that would be great! I believe it has something to do with nested lists, but how do I access the nested one?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You put the file data in a list:

```
PID = [open("PID.txt").read().split()]
```

That creates a list object with *one* value, the result of the `str.split()` call, which is also a list. Just remove the brackets:

```
PID = open("PID.txt").read().split()
```

If your codes are put one each on a line, you could just iterate directly over the open file object:

```
with open('PID.txt') as PID:
    URLList = ["http://www.abb.com/productdetails/" + code.strip()
               for code in PID if code.strip()]
```

where the `str.strip()` call removes any extra whitespace from the line (including the newline).

Answer (score 1):

> Right now only PID[0] works

`.split()` already returns a `list`,
so you don't need to wrap it in `[]`

So

```
PID = open("PID.txt").read().split()
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried taking away the split but it went kind of strange and put it all in 1 part of the list! Thanks for this, it worked!